# Forward fill values in mysql view

Tags: mysql

In python we have forward fill function - ffill how can I replicate the same logic in MySQL?

| order_id | status | order_value | handler_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | X | 1000 | 2001 |
| 101 | Y | null | 2001 |
| 101 | Z | null | 2001 |
| 101 | X | 1200 | 4001 |
| 101 | Y | null | 4001 |

I want to forward fill the order value (which is only stored where status is X and rest statuses order value is null) for each handler_id in that order_id.

How to achieve that?

Expected result -

| order_id | status | order_value | handler_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | X | 1000 | 2001 |
| 101 | Y | 1000 | 2001 |
| 101 | Z | 1000 | 2001 |
| 101 | X | 1200 | 4001 |
| 101 | Y | 1200 | 4001 |

Comment: What is your MySQL version? And the `order_value` will only fill `NULL` values having the same `order_id+handler_id` combination, right? What if for `handler_id=2001`, the `X=1000`, `Y=1100` and `Z=NULL`?

Comment: Version is 8.0. Yes the same order_id+handler_id. Also, the case you mentioned won't exist.Since, the values in status apart from X is null. Hence whatever that order_id + handler_id has the order value in X status will be forward filled until a new handler_id in the same order_id or a new order_id a found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT order_id, 
       status,
       MAX(order_value) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id, handler_id) order_value,
       handler_id
FROM tablename
```

If you want to update the table join to the table a subquery that returns the max `order_value` for each combination of `order_id` and `handler_id`:

```
UPDATE tablename t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT order_id, handler_id, MAX(order_value) order_value
  FROM tablename       
  GROUP BY order_id, handler_id
) m ON m.order_id = t.order_id AND m.handler_id = t.handler_id
SET t.order_value = m.order_value
WHERE t.order_value IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=953f4c0fe71261159253fceafd1a0239).